# Как добавить событие пользовательского элемента управления?

Tags: asp.net, c#

Создаю пользовательский контрол через файл кода.
В нем переопределяю метот рендер и генерю что то типа:
     writer.Write("<p  style=\"position: relative;width:auto;left:5%; margin-right:0px; margin-left:0px; font-weight: bold; float:left;\">");
            writer.Write(sender);
            writer.Write("</p>");
            writer.Write("<p style=\"margin:0px 0px 0px 0px ; width:20%; position:relative; text-decoration:underline; color: #00FFFF; float:right\">");
            writer.Write(date);
            writer.Write("</p>");

```
        writer.Write("<span  style=\"width: 60%;position: relative; left:5%; right:20%; background-color:"+color+"\" align=\"justify\"  >");
        writer.Write(text);
        writer.Write("</span>");
```

Затем мне нужно создать событие например клика мыши по этому контролу, КАК?
Знаю способ добавления кнопки в разметку и через делегат определить событие.
Так как сделать событие клика по всему контролу без кнопки, скажем по генерируемому div или всему контролу?

п.с. в коде при использовании метода AddAtributes - это не катит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что-то вроде

```
writer.Write("<span onclick=\"myJsFunction()\" style=....
```

не подойдет?

В клиенстком коде тогда определить эту `myJsFunction()` и даже если надо инициировать постбак оттуда.